Loading JSON file with Databricks Autoloader
I am trying to read a nested JSON file using simple spark.read.json and it is giving me expected result with proper schema definition.
But when am trying to do the same using databricks Autoloader code, it is only giving me the root elements and not the nested elements.
#Working code
    df = spark.read.json(f'abfss://container@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/trend/", multiline=True)
    df.printSchema()


Correct Output
Id: string (nullable = true)  
Scene: struct (nullable = true)
      Expose: array (nullable = true)
         Element: struct (containsNull = true)
            Expose1: array (nullable = true)

#Not working code
     df1 = (spark.readStream
       .format("cloudFiles")
       .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation",'abfss://container@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/checkpoint/bronze_to_silver/trend')
       .option("multiline", True)
       .load('abfss://container@dev.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/trend/'))

    df1.printSchema()

InCorrect Output
Id: string (nullable = true)  
Scene: string (nullable = true)


Have a look at this link may solve your issue...
